Py4J Gateway: Unable to Connect to Py4J Main Server, but Callback Server Works
Environment:
Windows 10 Pro 2009 Build 10.0.19041.3636
Python 3.12.2
Py4J 0.10.9.7
pip 24.0
keyboard 0.13.5
Issue:
I am using Py4J to access Java instances but encountering connection issues with the main server, while the callback server responds normally.
Background:
I'm not familiar with Java, so instead of compiling and running Java code, I decided to replicate the server in Python to diagnose connection issues. I initially set the main server to listen on port 25333 and the callback on 25334. After encountering connection issues with the main server, I changed the ports to 25334 for the main server and 25335 for the callback, but the problem persists.
Server code:
import time
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway, GatewayParameters, CallbackServerParameters


class SimulatedJavaService:
    def __init__(self):
      pass


def main():
    gateway = JavaGateway(
        gateway_parameters=GatewayParameters(port=25334, address='127.0.0.1'),
        callback_server_parameters=CallbackServerParameters(port=25335, address='127.0.0.1')
    )

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("beende Server...")
    finally:
        gateway.shutdown()
        print("Server sauber herunter gefahren.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Client code:
import logging
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway, GatewayParameters

# Logging Konfiguration
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

def connect_to_server():
    try:
        gateway = JavaGateway(gateway_parameters=GatewayParameters())
        logging.info("Verbindung mit Java Server erfolgreich.")
        return gateway
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Verbindung mit Java Server NICHT erfoglreich: %s", e)
        return None


def main():
    try:
        gateway = JavaGateway(gateway_parameters=GatewayParameters(port=25334))
        service = gateway.entry_point.getService()
        #uptime = service.getUptime()
        #logging.info("Service uptime: %s", uptime)
        #service.startService("Beispiel - Service")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Sonstige Fehler: %s", e)
    finally:
        try:
            if 'gateway' in locals() and gateway:
                gateway.shutdown()
                logging.info("Verbindung geschlossen.")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("Konnte die Verbindung nicht beenden: %s", e)       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Attempts to connect to ports 25334/25335 using a simple socket script shows that it's only possible to connect to the callback server, not the main server.
import socket

# 25335 geht
# 25334 geht nicht

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 25335))
    print("Verbindung erfolgreich")
except socket.error as e:
    print("Fehler beim Verbinden: ", e)
finally:
    s.close()

Even when I change the server code to the following:
 gateway = JavaGateway(
        gateway_parameters=GatewayParameters(port=25334, address='127.0.0.1')
    )

I am unable to establish a connection.
Question:
Why does only the callback server respond, while attempts to connect to the main server fail consistently?
